# /usr/bin/cmake: is a directory. Not able to grab the version of cmake?

Tags: cmake

I just have installed CMAKE in my ubuntu machine.. So when I do whereis cmake, it gives me the actual path

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~/CMAKE/cmake-2.8.11$ whereis cmake
cmake: /usr/bin/cmake
```

But whenever I try to get the version of cmake, I always get the below message.. I am not sure what wrong I am doing here?

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~/CMAKE/cmake-2.8.11$ /usr/bin/cmake --version
-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: is a directory
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Hi, could you please detail the procedure you followed to install cmake? Is there a reason why you didn't use the existing package? (`apt-get install cmake`) Did you check whether /usr/bin/cmake/cmake is what you're looking for, which would indicate a badly configured installation, which will in turn be apparent when you detail how you installed it?

Comment: @roadmr: I was following this [wiki](http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/operating_systems/linux/installation/downloading_compiling_and_installing_cmake_on_linux.php) to do the installation of cmake.. I just changed the path to /usr/bin/cmake that's all

Comment: Sorry, this is the full path I am supposed to use to make it working- `/usr/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --version`But is there any way such that I always use camke --version to see the version instead of using the full path everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The --prefix option is not where the binary file is. It's where all files are installed under. You need to `rm -rf /usr/bin/cmake` and just do `sudo apt-get install cmake` to install the cmake package on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks dobev for the suggestion.. Do you know what will be the path where cmake will get installed after doing this `sudo apt-get install cmake` ?

Comment: If you install from a package it will most likely be in `/usr/bin`,  meaning you can call it without an absolute path (i.e. just `cmake`).

Comment: @roadmr: Thanks for suggestion.. Are you sure, if I am doing `rm -rf /usr/bin/cmake` then it won't cause any issue.. right? And then I can directly use `sudo apt-get install cmake` to install the cmake again?

Comment: Yes. You installed it incorrectly, and the `/usr/bin/cmake` that exists and is a directory, is a result of that.

Comment: Yup.. I just tried it.. Now it works fine.. Thanks a lot.. I also have one more question somewhat related to `apt get` [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356901/fatal-error-log4cxx-logger-h-no-such-file-or-directory).. Can you help me here? Pardon my ignorance.. This is my first time doing these things..