# fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo

I am getting this error whenever I am compiling my c++ code from command line.

`fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory`

Is there any easy way to download the log4cxx package from the command line using `apt get`?

I do found the [wiki](http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-build-log4cxx-from-source) which talks about downloading it and compiling it step by step.. But is there any way from `apt get` that we can use?

**Update:-**

This is what I am getting while install `sudo apt-get install liblog4cxx10-dev`

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblog4cxx10-dev : Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

What wrong I am doing here? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the development package, `liblog4cxx10-dev`. You need to install it to compile code which uses the library.

Comment: Thanks dobev for the suggestion.. So the syntax should be like this `sudo apt-get install liblog4cxx10-dev` to download it?

Comment: This is what I got after installing it- broken package - `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblog4cxx10-dev : Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
`

Comment: Then try to install `libaprutil1-dev` by itself to see why it seems to be broken. You may need to do `apt-get -f install` as well.